# Why is a Möbius loop not a surface?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

In a course on topological graph theory, we defined a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ simply as a compact subset of $\mathbb R^3$. By this definition, how does it follow that a Möbius loop is not a surface?

Does it not contain all its accumulation points, and is it not bounded?

Comment: I'm sure there were other things in the definition as well. We need to know them before we can answer your question.

Comment: By that definition a sphere $:= \{x^2 + y^2 + z^1 \leq 1 \ | \ x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a surface as well, which seems off.

Comment: This is a terrible definition of a surface which does not agree with standard definitions. In addition to the closed ball, say, a one-point set of the Cantor set or the Menger curve qualify as surfaces with this "definition". Ask your instructor for a clarification.